# Nodejs how to write hosts with permissions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, hosts

```
fs.access(hostPath, fs.W_OK, function(err){
     console.log(err ? 'no access' : 'can write');
})
```

The result is 'no access' definitely. Can we use nodejs to rewrite hosts file?

Comment: You can, by running your Node program as root.

Comment: It is useful and it runs well. But I wanna make it as a web app then others can change their local hosts file. Can it be done that web app get the user's permissions?

Comment: Wait, you want to run this app in a browser? That's not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for you answer